# Multiple Database Usage, Second Connection After Login

Tags: .net-core

There is a scenario like in the picture. There is a common database. Customers are connecting to the same database. After the connection, company-specific information is kept in a separate database. The **connecting string** is pulled from the company information in the database after the user logs in. How can I do this logic in .net core. I'm new and need ideas.

[Click to see the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvb6U.png)

When the user logs in, company information is also taken as in the picture.

[Click for user company information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb1p2.png)

I can't define it in the "startup.cs" file because the user needs to be logged in.

Where and how can I define the connecting clause? Can you give an idea?

[Startup.cs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnCzx.png)

[appsettings.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrgNb.png)

[login method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI9yH.png)

In the login method, I need to migrate first. To create the tables. If there are tables, I need to connect to the company's product table. Can this special link be added to swagger too?

Comment: Can you provide some code ?

Comment: What kind of project are you working on? is it asp.net core web app(razor/mvc) or  a web-api project?

Comment: I made an update.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically within .net core project you can utilise DBFactoryBase class, and create a constructor which accept appsettings json key to fetch another connection string.

[image]